# Problems populating a ListView with Office keys

Tags: c#

I'm using a ListView for my project which finds installed programs, windows keys, and office keys. The problem is to locate, decrypt, and display the decoded keys on the ListView. The code is looking for all versions of Office which is what I want it to do, but how do I show the results in the ListView? `String` is working on other searches, but `byte[]` does not. The code to find the office version is:

```
namespace MSOfficeKeyDecoder
{
public class OfficeKeyDecoder
{        
    public enum Key { XP, Office, Office10, Office10X64, Office11, Office11X64, Office12, Office12X64, Office13, Office13X64, Office14, Office14X64, Office15, Office15X64 };
    public static byte[] GetRegistryDigitalProductId(Key key)
    {
        byte[] DigitalProductId = null;
        RegistryKey registry = null;
        switch (key)
        {
            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office10:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\\\Microsoft\\Office\\10.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office11:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\11.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office12:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\12.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office13:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\13.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office14:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\14.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office15:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\15.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office10X64:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\10.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 11 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office11X64:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\11.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 12 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office12X64:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\12.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
               break;

            // Open the Office 13 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office13X64:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\13.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
               break;

            // Open the Office 11 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office14X64:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\14.0\\Registration\\{91140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}",
                     false);
                break;

            // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
            case Key.Office15X64:
                registry =
                  Registry.LocalMachine.
                    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\15.0\\Registration\\",
                      false);
                 // TODO: Open the registry key.
                 break;
        }
        if (registry != null)
        {
            // TODO: For other products, key name maybe different.
            DigitalProductId = registry.GetValue("DigitalProductId") as byte[];
            registry.Close();
        }
        return DigitalProductId;
    }
}
}
```

And then in the ListView:

```
byte[] result1 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office10);
byte[] result2 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office11);
byte[] result3 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office12);
byte[] result4 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office13);   
byte[] result5 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office14);
byte[] result6 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office15);
byte[] result7 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office10X64);
byte[] result8 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office11X64);
byte[] result9 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office12X64);
byte[] result10 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office13X64);
byte[] result11 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office14X64);
byte[] result12 = OfficeKeyDecoder.GetRegistryDigitalProductId(OfficeKeyDecoder.Key.Office15X64);
//
//
// ListView Control:
//
//
ListViewItem row2 = new ListViewItem(String.Format(OfficeNameDecoder.ProductName));
row2.SubItems.Add(String.Format(OfficeProductIDDecoder.ProductID));
row2.SubItems.Add(String.Format(OfficeVersionDecoder.ProductVersion));
row2.SubItems.Add(String.Format(OfficeKeyDecoder.DecodeOfficeKey(result11))); 

ProgramsLvw.Items.Add(row2);
```

Result 11 is Office 2010 on x64 system. If I use result 1 to 10 I get a null reference.

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Comment: You have a huge pile of code pasted there for what seems like it should be a very simply-reproduced issue. Can you simplify your code to a minimal example?

Comment: Hello I'm using win forms..

Comment: The issue is that when its searching for the office DigitalProductID am getting a Thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (System.NullReferenceException)

Comment: The issue is that when its searching for the office DigitalProductID am getting a Thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (System. NullReferenceException)". If anybody can give me an example of how to check if the reg key is there first and if not continue to the next key to find the DigitalProductID key within the code im using any help would be appreciated as im newish to c#

Comment: I Think it would be easer if I just looked for a certain program in registry and displayed it in list view. If the program is not installed on another computer the list view shows a blank row were that program should be as the rows are numbered. How would I go about removing the blank row from list view so anything installed will be shown in sink ??

Comment: The null reference is fixed